# ksql - enum and struct support for protobuf

Tags: ksqldb

I have the following message structure:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.test;

option java_multiple_files = true;

message Event1 {
  string event1 = 1;
}

message Event2 {
  string event2 = 1;
}

message Events {
  oneof oneof_type {
    Event1 event1 = 1;
    Event2 event2 = 2;
  }
}
```

I created the following stream:

```
CREATE STREAM TEST_STREAM (
    oneof_type STRING,
    event1 STRUCT<event1 STRING>,
    event2 STRUCT<event2 STRING>
  ) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'nano-events2',
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'PROTOBUF'
  );
```

And got null for all columns:
[image]

Stream log shows following:
[image]

How can I map this message into stream?

Answer (score 0):

This question was cross-posted on ksqlDB GitHub page: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/7830

Seems there is a bug: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/5265